# Pig accessing HBase using Spring Data Hadoop

Tags: spring, hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, spring-data

Has anyone got experience of using Spring Data Hadoop to run a Pig script that connects to HBase using Elephant Bird's `HBaseLoader`?

I'm new to all of the above, but need to take some existing Pig scripts that were executed via a shell script and instead wrap them up in a self-contained Java application. Currently the scripts are run from a specific server that has Hadoop, HBase and Pig installed, and config for all of the above in `/etc/`. Pig has the HBase config on its classpath, so I'm guessing this is how it know how to connect to HBase

I want to have all configuration in Spring. Is this possible if I need Pig to connect to HBase? How do I configure HBase such that the Pig script and the Elephant Bird library will know how to connect to it?